# My thesis statement sounds awkward, should I add more commas?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Thesis statement: " Between both republics, the second republic is more advantageous for interest groups than the first republic because of the continuous increase size of government."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think adding commas will add clarity. How about this?

> Due to the continuously increasing size of government, the second republic offers interest groups more advantage than the first republic.

Shorter, and I think captures what you're after.